Connection between SQL Server and Airflow: [Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)
I am trying to connect SQL Server and Airflow. While trying to establish connection I got the following issue:

[Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect).

You can find my code here and screenshot of the error.
import pendulum
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pyodbc

local_tz = pendulum.timezone("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur")


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 3, 26),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False
    #'retries': 1,
    #'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    '1.1.initial_onboard_customer',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Transfer data from onboard.public.customer to report.public.onboard_customer',
    schedule_interval=None,  # You can specify your desired schedule interval here
    catchup=False,
    tags = ['Initial Data Load', 'UAT']
)



def transfer_data():
    try:
        # Get connection details from Airflow's connection pool
        source_conn = BaseHook.get_connection('UAT_DB')
        # dest_conn = BaseHook.get_connection('UAT_report_db_connection_string')

        # Connect to the source database
        source_conn_str = f"dbname={source_conn.schema} user={source_conn.login} password={source_conn.password} host={source_conn.host} port={source_conn.port}"
        print(source_conn_str)
        source_conn = pyodbc.connect(source_conn_str)
        print(source_conn)

        # Connect to the destination database
        # dest_conn_str = f"dbname={dest_conn.schema} user={dest_conn.login} password={dest_conn.password} host={dest_conn.host} port={dest_conn.port}"
        # dest_conn = psycopg2.connect(dest_conn_str)

        with source_conn.cursor() as source_cur:

            # Get customer details from the source database
            query = "Select TOP 10 * from [dbo].[Banks];"
            result = source_cur.execute(query)
            print(result)
        

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error occurred while transferring data:", e)
        raise


# Define the PythonOperator to execute the transfer_data function
transfer_data_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='1.1.initial_onboard_customer',
    python_callable=transfer_data,
    dag=dag
)

enter image description here
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Seems like you installed unixodbc (the API) on the host, but did you also install either "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" or "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server" so that the host has the ability to communicate with Microsoft SQL Server instances? Ref: Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux)

Also, host and port are not DSN and Connection String Keywords and Attributes for ODBC Driver for SQL Server. The host name (and optional instance name or port number) are specified using the server keyword, e.g.: Server=yourServerNameOrIpAddress,1433; or Server=yourServerNameOrIpAddress\yourInstanceName;

@AlwaysLearning I have used ODBC and it is working now.
